# Git rebase A-B-C-D: Parent A has child B and child C, and both B&C are parents of D

Tags: git, parent-child, rebase

I have a tree that looks like the following

```
  B
 / \
A   D
 \ /
  C
```

B and C don't conflict. What I want is it to show in my history as A-B-C-D.

How can I do this in git? I've searched but I can't find an answer I feel applies. I'm concerned to make a change because I don't want to make things worse and I don't know how I would undo it (is there a way to undo the last git command in git?)

Comment: Are you trying to change the history or just visualize it differently?

Comment: @djs I want both. I don't care how B or C is timestamped just as long as it's A-B-C-D in history. In other words A is a parent of B, B is a parent of C, C is a parent of D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test things out, simply clone your repository and play in the clone.

```
$ git clone your_repo test_repo
$ cd test_repo
```

In your case, `D` should just be a merge commit, which doesn't contain much if `B` and `C` don't conflict. So a simple rebase will work

```
$ git rebase branch_of_B branch_of_C
```

Try this in an empty repository:

```
echo A > file1
git add file1
git commit -m A
git checkout -b B
echo B > file2
git add file2
git commit -m B
git checkout master
git checkout -b C
echo C > file3
git add file3
git commit -m C
git checkout -b merge_branch
git merge B
echo D > file4
git add file4
git commit -m D
```

You now have this (run `gitk --all`):

```
   B
  / \
 A   M - D
  \ /
   C
```

and you're on `D`. You can issue

```
$ git rebase B
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: C
Applying: D
```

And you're left with:

```
A - B - C' - D'
 \
  C
```

with `C'` and `D'` identical to `C` and `D` in terms of "contents". If you want to clean up, you can remove branch `C` in this example, but you'll have to force it since that will make the original `C` commit dangle.

```
$ git branch -D C
```

Comment: A B C D commits are all on the same branch. I did `git rebase <hash-of-B> <hash-of-C>` instead of branch-of. That didn't work, instead it left me with a commit not connected to any of my branches. So then I rechecked out my branch and did `git rebase <hash-of-C>` which leaves me with A-B-C, and D has disappeared. Since D was a merge commit I guess it should have disappeared?

Comment: If `D` was just a merge commit of branches without any conflict, then yes it is normal that it disappears (just like `M` did in my example). It doesn't contain any information except for recording that `B` and `C` were merged.

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you explain why the first git rebase command I did didn't work and why the second one did?

Comment: I'm guessing the first command did work, you were just in a "detached HEAD" state which is bit weird to work with. Creating a branch on the spot would most likely have made everything look normal again.

Comment: git-rebase will not save merge commits. In your graph above, D has a single parent, and thus is not a merge commit. So, I still question exactly what you're doing here. The solution above is not a good way to work with git, so please don't do that. Without knowing your exact goal, one brute force way to accomplish something similar would be to create a new branched based on B~1 and then cherry-pick each commit you want. Keep in mind that rewriting history means all the commit hashes change, not just the timestamps.

Comment: @djs are you saying my graph or mat's graph? you'll have to excuse me I don't use SO too often. if you mean my graph I can tell you examining commit D I could see it had two parent hashes listed(B&C) before making the rebase changes. And are you saying Mat's answer is wrong? I marked it as correct because it seemed to be correct.

Comment: @test Apparently you're graph is meant to be read horizontally. I read it vertically. So, ignore everything I said.